# Why can an array be sorted _after_ it is logged?

Tags: javascript, callback, closures

Given the following code:

```js
const obj1 = { a: 2 };
const obj2 = { a: 3 };
const obj3 = { a: 1 };

const sortedArray = [obj1, obj2, obj3];
const unsortedArray = [obj1, obj2, obj3];

console.log('Sorted:', JSON.stringify(sortedArray));
console.log('Unsorted:', JSON.stringify(unsortedArray));

sortedArray.sort((one, two) => one.a - two.a);
```

I would expected both `console.log`s to output the objects in the order they were defined - after all, `sortedArray.sort` is only called *after* the `console.log`, and as far as I know, the log is executed synchronously.

However, the [actual output](https://codesandbox.io/s/m31wo5rp7x) is:

```
Sorted: 
[{"a":2},{"a":3},{"a":1}] 
Unsorted: 
[{"a":2},{"a":3},{"a":1}]
```

How come?

Comment: Oops! For anyone coming across this later: the `JSON.stringify` I added here to format it more easily for StackOverflow actually prevented this issue from showing up, the reason for which is explained in the answer to the duplicate.

Comment: What's the problem here, objects are being printed in the correct order only.

Comment: Although I haven't looked at the dupe target, I believe this is because a console log is evaluated live. I.e. it's not a snapshot.

Comment: @Prometheus the order is correct, but the log shows the sorted array which was called after the log.

Comment: @Prometheus I explained that in my first comment. The order is correct because I called `JSON.stringify` here, which I didn't do when I first encountered this issue.